# Compiling pgAudit for PostgreSQL 14

Tags: postgresql, pgaudit

I am working on enabling pgAudit in PostgreSQL 14 by following the steps outlined in the "Build pgAudit against a binary installation of PostgreSQL." However, I am encountering multiple errors during the generation of pgaudit.dll.

Here's a summary of the steps I've taken:

- Installed PostgreSQL 14 in "D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL"
- Installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017"
- Downloaded pgAudit-16.0
- Created a Build folder
- Copied pgaudit.c to the Build Folder (attached)
- Created pgaudit.def file in the Build Folder (attached)
- Created compile_response_file.txt in the Build Folder (attached)
- Created link_response_file.txt in the Build Folder (attached)

Used the following to compile:

```
cl /c @.\compile_response_file.txt .\pgaudit.c
link.exe @.\link_response_file.txt /OUT:".\pgaudit.dll" .\pgaudit.obj
```

[image]

Download the Build Folder:
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsE8HLBpjnjdrW3S_9TYxh5nufpy?e=PZ6MRa

Comment: The details needed to answer the question should in your question, not on 3rd party sites.

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a painting of the error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include it as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Comment: Where are you referencing your summary?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.